# My answer citing another answer was deleted

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers, specific-answer

There is a question I answered on Stack Overflow back in 2018. It has been there for 6 years, protected as a community wiki, and has 166 votes.

[How do I remedy "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-been/11439003?noredirect=1#comment132301753_11439003)

Yesterday, it was deleted saying that all of that could be written as a comment. It was deleted without me getting any say or chance to raise an objection.

Most people don't read all of the comments anyway. And obviously my answer had value or it would not have been changed to a community wiki years ago. How can I get this answer undeleted?

Answer (score 22):

Copying answers wholesale from elsewhere on Stack Overflow hasn't ever been allowed, even with proper attribution.

That the post was old and/or received lots of votes isn't a mark in its favor, it just means a moderator has not come across it yet and realized it was a full copy of an existing answer elsewhere.

Thanks for bringing to my attention though that the question Hans answered has not been closed as a duplicate of the one you linked, though, I've re-cast my dupe close vote.

The proper course of action here is to close the question Hans answered as a duplicate of the one you answered. That will add the former question to a list of related questions associated with the latter, and allow readers to see similar answers more easily, without you needing to repeat content across the site.

Comment: Are you sure that the answer from Hans is applicable to the other post (or the other way round)? Debugging Silverlight (Web) projects worked a little bit different from debugging desktop applications in VS. I don't think they should be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @BDL I have not done Silverlight development, but as you can see from the answers on both questions, there's _significant_ overlap in the various solutions recommended (and well-received) on each. Given that jp2code's now-deleted answer had **166** score, I find it... highly unlikely that it did not apply to the question it was posted under.

Answer (score 19):

> It was deleted it without me getting any say or objection.

Yes, that is how deletion normally works on Stack Overflow. Your content is licensed, including to Stack Exchange Inc., under a Creative Commons license; **the company is not providing a hosting service to you**. If you want to ensure that your content stays up, put it on a blog.

> Most people don't read all of the comments anyway.

They don't read all the answers, either. Especially not when there are **more than a hundred** of them, all of them somehow addressing a single IDE warning.

> And obviously my answer had value or it would not have been changed to a community wiki years ago.

If you look at the question, you'll notice that *all* of the answers have been changed to community wiki. **This is not actually a mark of approval or quality**. If anything, it's a mark (very inconsistently applied) of importance of the question.

That said, I'm a little confused. You call this "my answer", and seem invested in its continued existence on the site; yet at the same time you acknowledge that it is a cross-post of someone else's work, and don't seem to have any problem with your creation of the answer being de-emphasized (by marking it as community wiki). **Do you not sense an internal contradiction there?** Yes, there was a +166 next to text that resulted from you pressing keys. But you were not going to get more reputation from further upvotes, and it wasn't your thought in the first place.

Aside from that, the moderator's feedback (I assume this is a form comment) was clear:

> Do not duplicate entire answers from other questions. If it is a duplicate question then vote to close as such and/or leave a comment once you earn enough reputation.

If an answer can be cross-posted like that and make sense, the question is a *textbook* duplicate. **We don't want duplicates** hanging around unrecognized. We want to drive traffic to the canonical version of a question. Content can be *migrated* from one question to another by moderators, in a way that preserves the authorship record; but usually it's deemed sufficient to use the duplicate-marking system, which generates backlinks to other versions of the question.

Comment: I'm not interested in online reputation. In fact, it hurts me more than it helps. When I search this site, most of my help comes from other questions with answers that were closed as duplicates. Usually because what I search for is rarely worded the same as the first question asked. I don't think it's hurting the bandwidth here, either.

Comment: It's not a question of the site's bandwidth; it's a question of **organization**.

Comment: *"Usually because what I search for is rarely worded the same as the first question asked."* Which is why bring able to close as a duplicate is so good, as then you have multiple *different* ways of asking the *same* question all pointing to the *same* Q&A, @jp2code .